# Sending image from Android to Node.js server encodes it in URL style and can't be decoded well

Tags: java, android, node.js, urlencode

I'm trying to send a photo taken with my phone/emulator camera to a Node.js server, so I'm encoding it to make a string POST request.

I tried to encode it using other answers on the internet, with a byte array stream and a compressed version of the Bitmap. On Node.js I'm trying to decode it with a function that surely works; the problem is the encoding sent to Node.js from Java is bad.

Here is the encoding of the Bitmap:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
            final String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

And my POST request for the string looks like that (I'm using Volley for server interactions):

```
            StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            // response
                            Log.d("RESPONSE", response);
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            // error
                            Log.d("Error.Response", "ERROR" + error);
                        }
                    }
            ) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams()
                {
                    Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("image", imageEncoded);

                    return params;
                }
            };

            VolleySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is that my encoding gets some extra % characters when sent to the server, so it can't be decoded well. I thought that in my Node.js code I had to use chunks to make a full string, like this:

```
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      let body = [];
      req.on('data', (chunk) => {
      body.push(chunk);
      }).on('end', () => {
      body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
      body = body.split('=');

      // More code here
   }
```

My body would look like

```
    "image=iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHgAAACgCAIAAABIaz%2FH..."
```

so I had to use split to get only the encoding, but still it didn't work. Is there a way to transform this string in another that is not URL encoded like that? Or to get through the POST request without being modified like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the Volley library.  If so, you should consider using the JSONObjectRequest instead of the StringRequest.  It would look something like this, after you got your image into a JSON String format:

```
    String myImage = "{image:" + imageEncoded + "}"

    JSONObject obj = null;

    try {
        obj = new JSONObject(myImage);
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,obj,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            )} {


           @Override
           public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
               HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    headers.put("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

               return headers;
           }


        };
```